# Asp.net Validation just working for one property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, unobtrusive-validation

Following is my Model for Product

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Product Name")]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Enter Short Desciption")]
    [StringLength(200)]
    .   // other properties
    .   // Removed for brevity
}
```

And following is my View code

```
<div class="contentHolder">
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
       Html.Telerik().TabStrip()
           .Name("TabStrip")
           .Items(tabstrip =>
           {
               tabstrip.Add()
                   .Text("General")
                   .ContentHtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:700px" })
                   .Content(@<text>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="editor-label">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.Name)
                        </td>
                        <td class="editor-field">
                            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Product.Name)
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product.Name)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="editor-label">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Product.ShortDescription)
                        </td>
                        <td class="editor-field">
                            @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Product.ShortDescription, new { cols = "50%", rows = "3" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Product.ShortDescription)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
                </text>);
           })
           .SelectedIndex(0)
           .Render();
}
```

**Other than the `Name` property, validation isn't working.**

Comment: That's nice.  Did you have a question?

Comment: LOL...Yes i had and it was why the other validations(except Name) don't work. When i click save without entering anything in ShortDescription or long description, the unbrotusive validation message doesn't shows and the form is posted back

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to my problem. It's a bug or error in Asp.net MVC 3 as it is reported here : [Unobtrusive Client Hooks Not Generated Via TextAreaFor For Nested Model Properties](http://aspnet.codeplex.com/workitem/8576). This is the reason why the validations are aren't happening for ShortDescription in my case since i am using `@Html.TextAreaFor`.

Hope this is removed in MVC4