# ASP.NET MVC Authentication Redirect to Login Page when user route to the critical area

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, authentication, forms-authentication

I have an intranet application using windows authentication that works great. Now I have a requirement to expose an Admin area. This area should go to login page and get user password again.

Like when you are already logged into your Google account or your Facebook account and you need to re-enter your password when routing to a critical area.

This is an example of my application structure:

```
-IntranetApp
--Controllers
--Admin Areas
----Area1
----Area2
--Special Users Area
----Area1
----Area2
```

Thank you very much indeed for any help/pointers.
Now, I want to develop the mentioned code to my App using Asp.net MVC3?

## Additional information:

**Here are a few examples:**
When you are already logged into your Google account and you want to delete your account for security reasons Google asks you to re-enter your password.
Please log into your Google account, then go to [Edit 2-step Verification](https://accounts.google.com/b/0/SmsAuthConfig)

**Would you mind helping me with this, please?**

Comment: @MystereMan , Is this a spam comment. I am seeing this line used way too often

Comment: If you used Forms Authentication you could use different accounts for normal and admin usage. I don't think it's possible to implement re-login with Windows Authentication.

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay, Think it is a 10K reputation sindrome...

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay - no, it's not a spam comment.  It's a sarcastic comment to point out that the asker did not actually ask a question.  They just made a bunch of statements, then expected us to read their mind about what they actually wanted.

Comment: @MystereMan, actually you had posted the same comment in one of my question which was clear enough to understand what i meant to ask : [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8692298/asp-net-validation-just-working-for-one-property). So, I thought otherwise :-)

Comment: @PankajUpadhyay - and you did not actually ask a question there either.  You just made statements.  Are we supposed to read your mind?  If you don't ask a question, then we have to guess, and if we guess wrong we're just wasting everyones time.  So ASK your question, don't assume people can figure it out.

Comment: I am unsure why do you think there was no question. I said in bold letters that **Other than the Name property, validation isn't working.**

Answer (score 0):

What about using Roles?

eg

```
[Authorize(Roles="admin")]
public ActionResult Create() {
...
}
```

[Guru Gu has a good post about it](http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part9.htm), from the NerdDinner application.

Comment: He uses WindowsAuthentication. So user is already authorized and in some roles. He wanted re-login.

Comment: My question is about asking again user password for critical areas. **Google Ex:** when you Login to site and go to delete your user account for security reasons Google ask your password again.

Comment: I would use an custom AttributeFilter.

Answer (score 0):

In Asp.net MVC applications which use SQL Authentication via asp.net membership provider you can set the authentication for any controller or action by decorating it with Authorize attribute as Pure.Krome explained.

But for Creating an Intranet Site Using ASP.NET MVC, I would suggest to follow this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg703322%28v=vs.98%29.aspx). It's a nice article explaining utilizing windows authentication

Comment: Did you read the question? He said he is using WindowsAuthentication.

Comment: yes, i have read the question. He is using windows authentication but i am not sure what he is achieving with it if he doesn't know decorating controllers and actions for authentication. It seems he has only enabled the windows authentication and that's it. Therefore i am gave him a tutorial for intranet application and in case, he wants to develop an internet interface for his application, I explained the asp.net membership scenario.

Comment: He stated it clearly. Yet nobody seems to understand. He want re-login on Admin access.

Comment: ohhh k....now i get it....apologies for misundestanding....For that he can just popup a window for password or redirect to other page passing the username and ask for password...

Comment: Ask for what password? He is already logged in. Whenever he enters site he is authorized using WindowsAuthehtication.

Comment: The Integrated windows authentication in IIS is done automatically before each webrequest and we can not manually redo the authentication. Currently the only available approach may be manually call the WINDOWS LogonUser API to validate the user acccount, we need to provide the cleartext username/password when calling this API, do you think this is possible? If so , then read this article : [How to implement impersonation in an ASP.NET application](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;306158)